# How to redirect angular application to other component using default routing

Tags: angular

I have an angular application, I want to redirect to dashboard http://localhost:4200/dashboard component by hitting just http://localhost:4200 Here is the basic routing I am using. I tried this but not working

### app.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';



@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'  
    component: 'dashboardComponent'  ,
    
  }
]
export class AppRoutingModule {
  
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', 
    redirectTo: 'dashboard', 
    pathMatch: 'full'  
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: 'dashboardComponent'
    
  }
]
```